# forge run ios fails with message about imobi.dll

Tags: trigger.io

When I try to run "forge run ios", it fails with...

.lib\win-ios-install.exe
Cannot load library imobi.dll

I can't find imobi.dll on my system anywhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you up to date with the latest core version? I have run into issue like this in the past and downgrading to a previous version seems to help at time, not the best answer but can get you going, unless there is something in the newest version you need.

Comment: It has been a consistent issue for multiple versions. It just took me a while to be bothered enough to ask about it. I'm suspicious of my antivirus blocking it. I'll investigate and report back.